# Python argcomplete: can't see second level subparser argument

Tags: python, argparse

I use [argcomplete](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argcomplete/1.0.0) for commands completion and have the following sample code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK

import argparse
import argcomplete
from argcomplete import warn

def MySubCompleter(prefix, parsed_args, **kwargs):
    warn(parsed_args)
    return ['1','2']

def MySubSubCompleter(prefix, parsed_args, **kwargs):
    warn(parsed_args)
    return ['3','4']

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--parser')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='level1')
subparser = subparsers.add_parser('sub',help='sub')
subparser.add_argument('--subvar',dest='sub').completer = MySubCompleter

subsubparsers = subparser.add_subparsers(dest='level2')
subsubparser = subsubparsers.add_parser('subsub',help='subsub')
subsubparser.add_argument('--subsubvar',dest='subsubvar').completer = MySubSubCompleter

argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

Why when I do the following:

```
$ ./test.py sub subsub --subsubvar
```

I see only the following:

```
>  Namespace(level1='sub', parser=None)
   3  4
```

So I can't see level2='subsub' among the parsed_args (see Namespace).

Comment: Without the completer, does the parser work as expected?

Comment: It works even with the completer as expected. If I add print(args) into the end and execute: ./test.py sub subsub --subsubvar 1 <ENTER> then {'level1': 'sub', 'subsubvar': '1', 'parser': None, 'level2': 'subsub', 'sub': None}

Comment: Why is your completer returning 2 strings for an argument that only takes one?